Signatures not verified for bazel installation, but bazel is installed
I am trying to install Cuttlefish following the Android guide.
Running the
  pushd $dir
  # Install build dependencies
  sudo mk-build-deps -i
  dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
  popd

step, leads to the following error, before continuing with further steps:
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: bazel
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
/home/.../android-cuttlefish
/home/.../android-cuttlefish/frontend /home/bdarijan/android-cuttlefish
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package cuttlefish-frontend-build-deps


Now, I can manually install bazel:
/home/.../android-cuttlefish# bazel --version
bazel 7.2.1

but, when trying to build the packages, the following error appears:
root@ee-tik-vm062:/home/bdarijan/android-cuttlefish# ./tools/buildutils/b
uild_packages.sh
+++ dirname ./tools/buildutils/build_packages.sh
++ realpath ./tools/buildutils/../..
+ REPO_DIR=/home/bdarijan/android-cuttlefish
++ dirname ./tools/buildutils/build_packages.sh
+ INSTALL_BAZEL=./tools/buildutils/installbazel.sh
+ sudo ./tools/buildutils/installbazel.sh
Installing bazel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.16).
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1).
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.4.12).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8
Get:1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease [2,265 B]
Hit:2 https://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:3 https://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 https://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3D5919B448457EE0
Hit:6 https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.0/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3D5919B448457EE0
E: The repository 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I've tried following the advice given in this git thread, but it also didn't resolve it.
Does anyone have additional ideas?
Best
